# Communicating between a fragment and a non-parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Is it possible to communicate between a fragment and non-parent activity? I'm working on an app where I start an activity (non-parent) from a fragment, and I want the activity to communicate back to the fragment that initiated it and resume it. Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Bundle or intent `.putExtra`

Comment: @LunarWatcher Can you please post a more detailed answer instead of a comment?

Comment: It is posted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are sending the user to the fragment or activity using an intent, you can do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOrFragment.this, TargetActivity.class);
i.putExtra("name", data of almost any type);
startActivity(i);
```

Then to load....

```
boolean v = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("name", false);//Name of the extra, default value if not found
```

To explain:

The above first puts the extra. It accepts a large amount of variable types. `Integers`, `booleans`, even `parcelable` or `serializable` classes. Then you retrieve the intent using `getIntent` in the activity(you may need to use `getActivity` in a fragment) and to get the data you write `getIntent().get[type]Extra`

`putExtra` doesn't require a specific type. In the `Intent` class, `putExtra` is defined with a lot of variables, some of which include `integer`, `parcelable`(classes), `boolean`, `string`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `long` and many more.